# Jquery, get text value from divs on the same level using each()

Tags: jquery

Given the div structure below, I'm trying to get the text in each div.class content.

I've been using next() which only works for the first 2 elements and is a bit unwieldy.  Is there a way I can get the content values using selectors (would be more elegant)?

Because there are many holder divs on the page I need to use the selectors relative to each holder div.

Thanks,

```
$(".holder").each(function() {
var image = $(this).next().text();  //get value   
var title = $(this).next().next().text(); //gets value
} 

<div class="holder">
    <div class="field-image">
        <div class="content">content</div>  
    </div>
    <div class="field-title">
        <div class="content">content</div>  
    </div>
    <div class="field-location">
         <div class="content">content</div>  
    </div> 
   <div class="field-sector">
         <div class="content">content</div> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please correct your HTML? It looks like the `field-*` elements are children, yet you are using `.next` in your code. Without knowing the actual structure, we won't be able to provide a useful solution.

Comment: sorry about that, corrected

Comment: Any special reason to not use `$("> .field-* > .content", this).text()` per `field-*`?

Comment: You can use multiple class names for each element, so instead of the dash, seperate them using whitespace. That way you could select all of the fields with .field or a specific field with .field.title. I can write an answer with a demo if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just need to get the text content of each child (or of the `.content` element of each child):

```
$('.holder').each(function() {
    var texts = {};
    $(this).children().each(function() {
        // Assuming each child has only one class
        texts[this.className.replace(/^field-/, '')] = 
            $(this).find('.content').text();
    });

    // now do something with e.g. texts.image, texts.title, etc.
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  This seems like the best way to go

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".holder").each(function() {
  $(this).find('div[class*=field]').each(function() {
    var $image = $(this);
    var $content = $image.find('div.content');
    var text = $content.text();
  });
});
```